# Problems while using Gson to store HashMap

Tags: android, gson

I want to save a `HashMap` to a `SharedPreference` file. For that I am using `Gson` to `serialise-deserialise` by objects.
I get this error when creating the `HashMap` object from `String`.

```
Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 4
```

This is how I am trying to use `Gson`.

```
    public class Point {
        public int action;
        ....
    }
    ....

    public ArrayList<Point> gestInstance;
    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<Point>> savedGest;
    ....

    // Storing as a String in SharedPreference
    String serialisedGestures = gson.toJson(savedGest);
    mSharedPref.edit()
        .putString("saved_gestures", serialisedGestures)
        .commit();

    // Retrieving from SharedPreference
    String serialisedGest = mSharedPref.getString("saved_gest",
        "not_assigned");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type gestType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Point>>>() {
    }.getType();

    savedGest = gson.fromJson(serialisedGest, gestType); // Error!!
```

Why is this giving an error? Could someone suggest an alternative or workaround for this?

Comment: You are using a custom class point, I believe that's what's causing your problems. Either use some sort of primitive type holder or create a custom serializer.

Comment: looks like a typo. you are storing in shared prefs with "saved_gestures" and retrieving with "saved_gest"

Answer (score 4):

We can achieve using `GSON` lib

**Save to SharedPreferences**

```
HashMap<String,String> mHashmap = new HashMap<>();
mHashmap.put("test","SO");
Gson gson = new Gson();
String strInput = gson.toJson(mHashmap);// save this string in sharedPreferences
```

**Retrive HashMap from SharedPreferences**

```
String strOutput = "";//Retrive text from sharedPreferences
Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>(){}.getType();
HashMap<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(strOutput, type);
```